# Mgo library for Golang not searching by ID?

Tags: go, mgo

I am using mgo "gopkg.in/mgo.v2" Package and stuck on very first step, I am not able to find by ObjectID, I have a string message.ID, and 
is not being searched no matter what ,

```
session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer session.Close()
session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
coll := session.DB("aaaw_web").C("cron_emails")

err = coll.FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex(message.ID)).One(result)
```

However, the document I am looking for exists in Mongo.

Comment: Generally you pass a pointer to `Query.One()`. What is your `result`? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I got this result :                                                 
         **595f2c1a6edcba0619073263
         {ObjectIdHex("") 0   0  0    0 {         0    false 0    } 0 0 0  0 0 0 0}
         ObjectIDs must be exactly 12 bytes long (got 24)
not found**

Comment: Ok, then it's an exact duplicate of your previous question.